# canvas не позволяет выделить текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

После использования canvas не могу выделить текст как по дефолту (по символьно), не могу понять что не так. Менял z-index самого канваса и контента но не помогло. В чём может быть проблема?

Код здесь
[ссылка](https://codepen.io/jackson75063/pen/vYGQxQY)

```
<span>some text</span>
```

Comment: канва же поверх

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как его прокинуть назад?

Comment: добавить после канвы

Comment: и не понятно почему z-index не помог

Comment: @StrangerintheQ z-index не работает. еще есть варианты?

Comment: я же написал, добавить после канвы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, там текст выделается двойным кликом изначально и при замене `appendChild` на `prepend` поведение такое же. Дело в событиях.

Comment: `canvas {pointer-events: none;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы останавливаете событие и оно просто не добирается до вашего текста. Уберите `e.preventDefault();` и вашей функции onMouseMove на событии pointermove.

```
value: function onMouseMove(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  ... остальной код ...
  
}
```